# Heroku custom domain from hostgator

Tags: django, heroku

I have a django application that I launched with heroku. I have a challenge of adding my custom domain to change the www.example.heroku.com to www.example.com. I got my domain with hostgator and I have changed the cname to point to www.example.com.herokudns.com. but after 48 hours I am unable to use www.example.com and I contacted my domain provider which is hostgator but I was told I needed nameserver which is not provided by heroku. I am confused at this point as this is my first time of trying a custom domain with an heroku application

Answer (score 0):

Heroku doesn't use nameservers.  All you can do is point the CNAME in hostgator to your heroku app which is something along the lines of :

myapp.herokuapp.com

Double check that it is the right app domain.

You also need to add your custom domain to the heroku project through the heroku dashboard: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/custom-domains

Comment: I did changed it to www.myapp.herokudns.com